# What is a unique identifier and how to use it to select?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I use Selenium and I am trying to automate a task on a website and in order to select an item I have to use this:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_*whatever*
```

However, all the *whatevers* like `find_element_by_id`, by name, by tag name etc. are either unavailable or are shared by several items. The only one that seems to be unique to each item is a "data-id" number but there isn't a `find_element_by_data_id` function as far as I know.

I can get a unique identifier which looks like this:

```
div.item:nth-child(453)
```

It seems to fit since it doesn't change when I reload the page and is unique to only one item.

How can I use this unique identifier to select the object? Alternatively, could you suggest a way of how I could select the desired item?

Here's the HTML pertaining to the object:

```
    ...
</div>
<div data-id="3817366931"
     data-slot="secondary"
     data-classes="pyro"
     data-content="Level: 30<br/>"
     data-appid="440"
     class="item hoverable quality6   app440"
     style="opacity:1;background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/440/icons/c_drg_manmelter.b76b87bda3242806c05a6201a4024a560269e805.png);"
     data-title="Manmelter"
     data-defindex="595">
</div>
<div data-id="3820690816"
     data-slot="primary"
     data-classes="pyro"
     data-content="Level: 10<br/>"
     data-appid="440"
     class="item hoverable quality6   app440"
     style="opacity:1;background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/440/icons/c_drg_phlogistinator.99b83086e28b2f85ed4c925ac5e3c6e123289aec.png);"
     data-title="Phlogistinator"
     data-defindex="594">
</div>
<div data-id="3819377317"
     data-slot="primary"
     data-classes="pyro"
     data-content="Level: 10<br/>"
     data-appid="440"
     class="item hoverable quality6   app440"
     style="opacity:1;background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/440/icons/c_drg_phlogistinator.99b83086e28b2f85ed4c925ac5e3c6e123289aec.png);"
     data-title="Phlogistinator"
     data-defindex="594">
```

So the items in the two bottom boxes are the same. The one at the top is different. Let's I would like a way to select the item in the second box.

Comment: Please provide the corresponding `html`. Selector of any element depends on the structure of `html`

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by html? Do you mean a link to the website or the part of the html that pertains to the item?

Comment: The *part of the html that pertains to the item* and the related parent node should be enough to explain the selector and how to find that uniquely

Comment: Being unique is one thing, but is it a format your test can expect? Seems totally random to me, which is useless for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how easy it will be to automate the scenario based on the `html` structure like this. I would suggest you to talk to the devs to see if they can add some kind of ids to each parent `div` otherwise the selector will be too brittle. I also see the `data-id` attribute is unique in every case so that could be your best bet if you somehow know the ids beforehand. If you do not have any other options then css `nth-child()` function is the next most reliable mechanism. But, in that case you have to know the parent. `nth-child()` is well explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

On the other hand, if the intention is to find the second `data-slot` you can use the following `xpath`:

```
//div[@data-slot='primary'][2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! This is helpful. And yes, the code does seem non-standard and hard to automate. I'll just have to try and do my best at it.

Comment: Sorry Saifur, I forgot to ask. How could I implement the search for a data-id number?